# Site not opening on particular network provider

Tags: php, networking, network-programming, mtu

I have a site in php. Which is not opening only on particular service provider (BSNL India).

It is a MTU issue. If we change a system MTU from 1500 to 1458 site starts working.

I really want to know

1) Why this happens with few sites only & rest other works fine with MTU 1500.

2) Can we fix this from server side instead of asking user to reduce there MTU size.

Comment: It sounds like a firewall is blocking ICMP messages, which are needed for Path MTU Discovery.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery